# Can't find HC-05 communications speed (findBaud)

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-uno

I am trying out Arduino Uno + HC-05 using [this library](https://github.com/jdunmire/HC05). I don't think it is working properly. This is the Serial Monitor's output of the example "echo":

```
findBaud
Trying 4800... x
Trying 9600... x
Trying 19200... x
Trying 38400... x
Trying 57600... x
Trying 115200... x

No connection
No Connection, waiting...OK
```

None of the Communication speed works, but I manage to connect my Android phone (w/ Bluetooth Terminal) to the HC-05, which is why you see "OK" at the end of the output. But it is not able to echo my input from the Bluetooth Terminal.

The Arduino code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "HC05.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

HC05 btSerial = HC05(A2, A5, A3, A4);  // cmd, state, rx, tx

void setup()
{
  DEBUG_BEGIN(57600);
  btSerial.findBaud();
}

void loop()
{
  btSerial.println("Echo Server- type something");
  while (btSerial.connected())
  {
    if (btSerial.available())
    {
      btSerial.write(btSerial.read());
    }
  }
}
```

How I connect the HC-05 to Arduino:

I just follow the instruction(5V and GND; State, Rx and Tx to A5, A3 and A4 respectively) , except I don't have pin "cmd", but I do have pin "CFG", so I just assume that should be cmd and connect it to A2

Answer (score 0):

(I know I should comment instead of writting an answer, but I need 50 reputation)

Same here.

I tried with and without the lib and with different pins. I also tried an arduino micro and uno.

Always the same: the module's LED blink (when I send data trough RX/TX it seems) but I can't have any answer (neither when switching to command mode with "$$$" and neither with AT commands with KEY pin - on my module it is named EN, maybe for *enable*, I assume it is the same)

---

EDIT:

I should have RTFM. Especially [this](http://www.martyncurrey.com/arduino-with-hc-05-bluetooth-module-at-mode/).

Here are my findings :

- The bluetooth module is called HC-05 and the whole board I have is ZS-040.
- The EN pin is used to switch off the module, if set to LOW
- The small button switch can be pushed to enter command mode (I don't have a KEY pin)
- Speed is 9600 bauds by default and stay the same when entering command mode
- To debug your connection you can use the Android app called BlueSerial

For the record, here is my code :

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define HC05_STATE 5
#define HC05_RXD_ARDUINO_TXD 4
#define HC05_TXD_ARDUINO_RXD 3
#define HC05_EN 2

SoftwareSerial BTSerial(HC05_TXD_ARDUINO_RXD, HC05_RXD_ARDUINO_TXD); // RX | TX

void setup(void)
{
    pinMode(HC05_EN, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(HC05_EN, HIGH);  // just to be sure to enable the module, if not plugged it still works

    Serial.begin(9600);
    BTSerial.begin(9600);  // default speed

    Serial.println("Ready");
}

void loop(void)
{
    if (BTSerial.available())
    {
        Serial.print("< ");
        while (BTSerial.available())
            Serial.write(BTSerial.read());
        Serial.print("\n");
    }

    if (Serial.available())
    {
        Serial.print("> ");
        while (Serial.available())
        {
            char c = Serial.read();
            BTSerial.write(c);
            Serial.write(c);
        }
        Serial.print("\n");
    }
}
```